# Can ruby tell if it is called from an interactive shell or cron?

Tags: ruby, rake, command-line-interface

When I run a rake task by hand, I want to make Rails.logger log to STDOUT.
But not if the rake task is run by a cron job. Is there a way to find out, how the rake task got started?

```
task :my_env => :environment do
  if A_USER_IS_WATCHING_ME
    Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end
end
```

Comment: [`$stdout.tty?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-tty-3F) should work

Comment: It does. Thank you. Could you create an answer so I can set it as solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$stdout.tty?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-tty-3F) returns `true` if `$stdout` is associated with a terminal device (i.e. an interactive user) and `false` otherwise:

```
# test.rb
if $stdout.tty?
  puts "tty"
else
  puts "not a tty"
end
```

From bash:

```
$ ruby test.rb
tty

$ ruby test.rb > test.log
$ cat test.log
not a tty
```